# API response overwriting another API response inside of await Promise.all()

Tags: react-native, promise, axios

I'm developing a React-Native application that is hitting a few development APIs via LocalHost.

I am having an issue with calling two APIs within the same function, where (in most cases) the response from API(2) seems to be overwritten by the response from API(1).

**API(1) returns an array such as [1, 2, 3, 4]**

and

**API(2) returns an array such as ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']**

Calling both APIs within the same function returns [1, 2, 3, 4] for both responses. I'm definitely hitting two different URLS, hitting both APIs from my browser confirms that they send back different data.

Am I misunderstanding the use of await Promise.all() as far as mitigating this problem?

```
 async componentDidMount() {
    await this.getStuff();
  }

  getStuff = async () => {
    const [firstResponse, secondResponse] = await Promise.all([
            axios.get(`${API_URL}/quarry/equipment/s07`), //returns [1, 2, 3, 4]
            axios.get(`${API_URL}/quarry/materials/Q08`), //returns ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
    ]);
    console.log(firstResponse.data); // [1, 2, 3, 4]
    console.log(secondResponse.data); // [1, 2, 3, 4]
  };
```

This is a simplified version of the issue I'm having. I'm using Redux and Redux-Thunk to dispatch my asynchronous API calls, and I spent quite a while under the assumption that I was using them improperly. After bypassing the Redux action creators and redux-thunk, and boiling the requests down to this simple code, I get the same result.

Am properly using `await Promise.all([])` ?

Comment: I have some doubt that there is an issue in the sample code you shared, but maybe I'm missing something. Assuming your actual code is more complex, could it be outside of this code sample?

Comment: @Evert I had the same thought. So I reduced the API calls down to these 12 lines of code and had the same result as before

Comment: I just tested this same code with two public APIs (https://pokeapi.co/) and it worked just fine. Is it possible that the development server running my localHost APIs is the issue?

Comment: Yeah that could make sense! What are you seeing in your network tabs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was not with the requests being made from the React-Native application.

It was a scoping issue within the ColdFusion server running the APIs I was hitting. The developer that had set up the server found the problem and got it fixed.